# i want to send Listview Data to Another Activity in Android using json

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-listview

I want to send a `Listview` Data to another `Activity`.

check my code:

**ActorAdapater.java**

```
package anyname;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
    ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
            holder.tvDOB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
            holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
            holder.tvHeight = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
            holder.tvSpouse = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
            holder.tvChildren = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvDOB.setText("B'day: " + actorList.get(position).getDob());
        holder.tvCountry.setText(actorList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.tvHeight.setText("Height: " + actorList.get(position).getHeight());
        holder.tvSpouse.setText("Spouse: " + actorList.get(position).getSpouse());
        holder.tvChildren.setText("Children: " + actorList.get(position).getChildren());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDescription;
        public TextView tvDOB;
        public TextView tvCountry;
        public TextView tvHeight;
        public TextView tvSpouse;
        public TextView tvChildren;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
```

**Actors.java**

```
public class Actors {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String dob;
    private String country;
    private String height;
    private String spouse;
    private String children;
    private String image;

    public Actors() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Actors(String name, String description, String dob, String country,
            String height, String spouse, String children, String image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.country = country;
        this.height = height;
        this.spouse = spouse;
        this.children = children;
        this.image = image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }

    public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public String getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(String children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ANYNAME;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

    ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("json link here.xml");

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            }
        });
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }






}
```

***When users Click on Listview Content & Pass Listview Data to NewActivity.java***

Comment: Do you want to send whole actorsList or just the one selected?

Comment: one  selected listview content...to another activity

Comment: use `Intent` to send data to other `Activity`

Comment: So, you implement Parceable in your Actors class, put it as Extra in the intent and retrieve extra in the target activity. Which part of this process is the issue? What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent` to pass data from one `Activity` to another.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("key",value);//
......
startActivity(intent);
```

In your `NewActivity` access value as:

```
 variable=getIntent().getXXX("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to generate json (String) from your model. Put it to the `Intent` and start new `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared SharedPrefences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MYPrefrences", 0);
```

For save

```
Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();

Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson("MyObject");

prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);

prefsEditor.commit();
```

For get

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");

Actor actor = gson.fromJson(json, Actor.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Serializable (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) in your Actors.java class. In your setOnItemClickListener, use the following code:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(thisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

In your NextActivity.class, you can get back the object like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
YourClass object = intent.getSerializableExtra("key");
```

This will give you the whole object, with all its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this,

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long id) {

    Actors myActor = actorsList.get(position);

    // create JSON object from the above object with getter methods
    JSONObject myActorJSON = new JSONObject();
    myActorJSON.put("name", myActor.getName());
    myActorJSON.put("description", myActor.getDescription());
    myActorJSON.put("dob", myActor.getDOB());
    myActorJSON.put("country", myActor.getCountry());
    myActorJSON.put("height", myActor.getHeight());
    myActorJSON.put("spouse", myActor.getSpouse());
    myActorJSON.put("children", myActor.getChildren());
    myActorJSON.put("image", myActor.getImage());

    //you can send the Actors object or JSONObject to the new Activity
    // through intent as
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("ACTOR_OBJECT", myActor);    //Actors class should extend serializable interface
    i.putExtra("ACTOR_JSON_OBJECT", myActorJSON.toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and

```
    //Now in NewActivity.class extract tha data from intent as
Intent i = getIntent();
Actors receivedActorObject = (Actors)i.getSerializableExtra("ACTOR_OBJECT");
String JSONString = i.getStringExtra("ACTOR_JSON_OBJECT");
try {
    JSONObject receivedActorJSON = new JSONObject(JSONString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Let me know if it works for you...
And do mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Answer (score 0):

On your onClick method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Actor selectedActor = actorsList.get(position);
            JSONObject obj = new JsonObject();
            obj.put("name",selectedActor.getName());
            //add other values of actor like that
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActirity.this,otherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Actor",obj.toString());
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

In your receiving activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(i.getStringExtra("Actor"));
```

Also have a look at [Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)